# how to get text from Spanned object, modify it and again converts into spanned

Tags: android

I need to set text to a textview in List with containing some spanned items, So I am passing ArrayList of Spanned object in adapter, but at the time of setting i need to remove some unusual characters in Spanned object(text). And then after modifying i need to set that text to textview. i am trying following code for it.

// list is the ArrayList of Spanned Item and spanned contain some image.

`Spanned spanned = list.get(position); 
String text=Html.toHtml(spanned );
text.replace("#"," ");
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

By using above code, images in spanned doesn't display on textview.
How can i solve this issue. please help on this.